# I want to replace one single quote with two single quote I want replace ' -> '' like this

Tags: sql-server

I want to replace one single quote with two single quote I want replace ' -> '' like this 
Query:

```
UPDATE UniqueProds
SET OtherInvoiceName = REPLACE(@otherInvoiceName, '', '''')
WHERE HnyProdid = @ProductID
    AND attid IS NULL OR attid = ''
    AND AcInvoice = REPLACE(@AcInvoiceName, '', '''')
```

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Comment: I'm just trying to be kind, helping people to tag properly and get better attention and better answers - faster. (And ANSI SQL is the way to go when writing portable code.)

Comment: Please do include which dialect of SQL you are using in the tags (or which DBMS, if you prefer).  It helps get the right information to you.  The `@` symbols make it look a bit like Sybase of MS SQL Server, but we shouldn't have to guess — you should tell us.  In fact, unless I'm misremembering, when you ask, there's a red box pops up asking you specify the DBMS.

Comment: It's a bit clear, do you want to replace a single quote `'` with a double quote `"`. Or do you mean you want to escape single quotes (replace a single occurance of single quote with two single quotes `'` -> `''`)?

Comment: I want to replace one single quote with two single quote        I want replace ' -> '' like this

Comment: Then JonathanLeffler's answer is what you need (the first SQL Statement).

Answer (score 2):

For the match part, you need one single quote to start the string, two more to embed one single quote in the string, and one final single quote to close the string.  For the replace part, if you want to replace the single quote with two adjacent single quotes, you need two more single quotes.  Hence, assuming the rest of the syntax is OK:

```
update  UniqueProds 
set  OtherInvoiceName=REPLACE(@otherInvoiceName,'''','''''') 
where HnyProdid=@ProductID and attid is null or attid='' and
      AcInvoice=REPLACE(@AcInvoiceName, '''', '''''')
```

If you mean 'replace a single-quote `'` with a double-quote `"`', then obviously, the answer changes a bit — the match is the same but the replacement is much simpler.

```
update  UniqueProds 
set  OtherInvoiceName=REPLACE(@otherInvoiceName,'''','"') 
where HnyProdid=@ProductID and attid is null or attid='' and
      AcInvoice=REPLACE(@AcInvoiceName, '''', '"')
```

Comment: how I tag dbms...actually I am new in stackoverflow

Comment: Edit the question, and where you have the tag [tag:sql] add a tag such as [tag:SQL-server] or [tag:db2] or [tag:oracle] or [tag:mysql].

Comment: If you have errors, show the exact text of the error message in an edit to the question. Do not remove the original SQL; add your revised SQL.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'x'.

Comment: I am updating this ..........Proc_UpdateOtherInvoiceNameCK '523129435', '','3' x 6' Yoga Mat + Zippered Bag (Black)','3' x 6' Yoga Mat + Zippered Bag (Black)Test'

Comment: Pay attention.  Edit the question; do not post the extra information as comments.

Comment: Proc_UpdateOtherInvoiceNameCK '523129435', '','3'' x 6'' Yoga Mat + Zippered Bag (Black)','3'' x 6'' Yoga Mat + Zippered Bag (Black)Test'     If I am inserting This then updated right

Answer (score 0):

```
AcInvoicName = txtAcInvoice.Text.Split('_')[1].ToString().Replace("'","''");
```